# Custom ScrollView to render PDF using CGPDFDocument crashes app randomly

Tags: uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, cgpdfdocument

I am rendering PDF documents using a custom UIScrollView but lately this has been crashing the app randomly - sometimes crashes after PDF is rendered, sometimes after dismissing the UIViewController in which this custom ScrollView is a subview. I am unable to make any specific pattern about the crash. Need help in identifying the crash or any workaround suggestions.

```
critical: Stacktrace:

critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00012>
critical:   at CoreAnimation.CALayerDelegate.Dispose (bool) [0x00015] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4991/80b8487d/source/xamarin-macios/src/CoreAnimation/CALayerDelegate.cs:47
critical:   at Foundation.NSObject.Finalize () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4991/80b8487d/source/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:129
critical:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_virtual_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0001f] in <75fdc35757ef4b00a24457129d1dc3e2>:0
critical: 
Native stacktrace:

critical:   0   myappname                  0x00533b6f mono_handle_native_crash + 239
critical:   1   myappname                  0x0053ff25 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 293
critical:   2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x0d4e2e5b _sigtramp + 43
critical:   3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
critical:   4   myappname                  0x006fccfb xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 43
critical:   5   ???                                 0x23b0cdd8 0x0 + 598789592
critical:   6   ???                                 0x28ba4e5c 0x0 + 683298396
critical:   7   ???                                 0x22a23b08 0x0 + 581057288
critical:   8   ???                                 0x22a23091 0x0 + 581054609
critical:   9   myappname                  0x005afbec mono_gc_run_finalize + 812
critical:   10  myappname                  0x006203f3 sgen_client_run_finalize + 19
critical:   11  myappname                  0x006889e9 sgen_gc_invoke_finalizers + 249
critical:   12  myappname                  0x005b179a finalizer_thread + 762
critical:   13  myappname                  0x0064e4f5 start_wrapper + 661
critical:   14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0d4f3047 _pthread_body + 184
critical:   15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0d4f2f8f _pthread_body + 0
critical:   16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0d4f284a thread_start + 34
critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Comment: It seems like memory access error,could you share the code how you use the CGPDFDocument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to fix the issue as follows

The DrawLayer method wasn't overridden in the custom UIView. Instead, it was overridden in a custom CALayerDelegate and then the UIView's layer's delegate was being set to that custom CALayerDelegate. After re-reading the below paragraph several times and checking the code for any such delegate setting code, I was able to fix my issue.

> In addition, the view always assigns itself as the delegate of its
>   layer object. At this point, the view owns its layer and the
>   relationship between the view and layer must not change. You must also
>   not assign the same view as the delegate of any other layer object.
>   Changing the ownership or delegate relationships of the view will
>   cause drawing problems and potential crashes in your application.

I removed that delegate setting code and I don't see the crash anymore.